# 2 week sum ending on every second Tuesday

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have some data in a format like the reproducible example below (code for data input below the question, at the end). Two things:

1. Not all dates have a value (i.e. many dates are missing).
2. Some dates have multiple values, eg 16 June 2020.

```
#>        date value
#> 1 30-Jun-20    20
#> 2 29-Jun-20  -100
#> 3 26-Jun-20    -4
#> 4 16-Jun-20   -13
#> 5 16-Jun-20    40
#> 6  9-Jun-20    -6
```

For two week periods, ending on Tuesdays, I would like to take a sum of the `value` column.

So in the example data above, I want to sum ending on:

- two weeks ending on Tuesday 16 June 2020 (i.e. from 3 June 2020 - 16 June 2020, inclusive)
- two weeks ending on Tuesday 30 June 2020 (17 June 2020 - 30 June 2020 inclusive)
- I'd ultimately like the code to continue summing all two week periods ending on every second Tuesday for when there's more data.

So my desired output is:

```
#2_weeks_end     total
#30-Jun-20    -84
#16-Jun-20     21
```

Tidyverse and lubridate solutions would be my first preference.

Code for data input below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                date = c("30-Jun-20","29-Jun-20",
                       "26-Jun-20","16-Jun-20","16-Jun-20","9-Jun-20"),
                value = c(20L, -100L, -4L, -13L, 40L, -6L)
)
df
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution using findInterval().

```
df$date <- dmy(df$date)
df_intervals <- seq(as.Date("2020-06-03"), as.Date("2020-06-03")+14*3, 14)

df %>%
  mutate(interval = findInterval(date, df_intervals)) %>%
  mutate(`2_weeks_end` = df_intervals[interval+1]-1) %>%
  group_by(`2_weeks_end`) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(value))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  2_weeks_end   total
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-06-16    21
2 2020-06-30   -84
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option if you like weekly or any other unit that is in `lubridate` by default:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df%>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%b-%y"))%>%
    group_by(week_ceil = ceiling_date(date - 1L, unit = "week", week_start = 2L))%>%
    summarize(sums = sum(value))
```

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach that creates a reference table followed by a non-equi join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, date := as.Date(date, format = "%d-%b-%y")]

ref_dt = df[,  .(beg_date = seq.Date(from = floor_date(min(date), unit = "week", week_start = 3L),
               to = max(date), 
               by =  "2 weeks"))]
ref_dt[, end_date := beg_date +13L]

df[ref_dt, 
   on = .(date > beg_date,
          date <= end_date),
   sum(value),
   by = .EACHI]

##         date       date  V1
##1: 2020-06-03 2020-06-16  21
##2: 2020-06-17 2020-06-30 -84
```

Comment: with your `lubridate` answer, after the code gives me the weekly totals, is there any easy way to get the 2 weekly totals I was looking for? Would you recommend just summing using a lag operator, and then filtering out every second row? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I do not believe there is an easy way to get it to the 2 weekly totals - but I thought it was still nice enough to include even if it doesn't truly answer your quest.  Your idea is nice, but you would also need to account for missing weeks. That is, if nothing happened on 1/1/20, there would be no record to filter. So... if you can simplify and assume that every bi-weekly period has a result, there may be other approaches.